# Get values in between key words XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have an example xml string below:

`<String>`AAhelloBBworldCC!DD!`</String>`

And, I want to get the value in between of AA, BB, CC, and DD. My output should look like this:

```
<Data>
  <Samp>hello</Samp>
  <Name>world</Name>
  <Field>!</Field>
  <Elem>!</Elem>
</Data>
```

I'm thinking to use the `<xsl:analyze-string>` but I don't know how to do it. I just started doing it, but I don't know how to end it. This is my sample XSLTv2:

```
<xsl:template match="String">
    <xsl:variable name="val" select="'AA','BB','CC','DD'"/>
    <xsl:analyze-string select="normalize-space(.)" regex="[A-z]+">
        <xsl:matching-substring>
            <xsl:number value="index-of($val, regex-group(1))" format="01"/>
        </xsl:matching-substring>
    </xsl:analyze-string>
</xsl:template>
```

Your feedback is highly appreciated!.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

How about using tokenize() instead of xsl:analyze-string?

[Input]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data><String>AAhelloBBworldCC!DD!</String></Data>
```

[Stylesheet]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:variable name="elemName" as="xs:string+" select="('Samp','Name','Field','Elem')"/>

    <xsl:template match="Data">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="String">
        <xsl:for-each select="(tokenize(normalize-space(.),'AA|BB|CC|DD'))[string(.)]">
            <xsl:variable name="position" as="xs:integer" select="position()"/>
            <xsl:element name="{$elemName[$position]}">
                <xsl:value-of select="."/>
            </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[The result]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Data>
   <Samp>hello</Samp>
   <Name>world</Name>
   <Field>!</Field>
   <Elem>!</Elem>
</Data>
```

Comment: It is working, but what if the output name is different from each other? I edited my post in the output section. Thank you.

Comment: @Nathan I edited my answer. If the element name is determined by the tokenized position, this will be the solution.

Comment: To add a general observation here: use xsl:analyze-string if you need to process the delimiters, use fn:tokenize() if you don't.

Comment: @MichaelKay Good advice!